# Oscillating spring, speed close to the equilibrium: How is this answer not 1.5?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I have this question with the answer listed as $2.0\,\mathrm{m/s}$.

> "A $1.25\,\mathrm{kg}$ mass on a spring with a constant of $12.0\,\mathrm{N/m}$ is oscillating back and forth.
>   Its maximum speed is $2.5\,\mathrm{m/s}$. What speed will it have when it is $0.48\,\mathrm{m}$ from
>   equilibrium?"

But I'm struggling to understand that.

What I did was $mv^2 = kx^2$, which eventually translates down to $0.48\,\sqrt{12/1.25} \simeq 1.487\,\mathrm{m/s}$.

Is the answer just a simple mistake, or am I miscalculating this?

Comment: Why do you think the kinetic energy would be equal to the elastic potential energy?  Rather, they will add to a constant value.  You could use $\Delta E_k=-\Delta E_e$

Comment: I added MathJax, please use it in the future for typesetting math. See [guide](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and links therein.
I've also added the tag "Homework and exercises." Please use it in the future for similar questions. Also check out the [meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and the [guide](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi Jason and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: The idea to use the energy conservation is right, you just need to be careful about which $x$ and $v$ you use (by which I mean at which time). You need however to use additional relations between the dynamics of the position and the speed to find the correct answer. If it reassures you, I find 2 $m/s$.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula mv^2 = kx^2 is baseless. You should write the energy conservation law correctly.